# Metro App handle open link / url loading in webview

Tags: c#, url, webview, event-handling, microsoft-metro

i have a banner which contain click zone to url like this :

```
playMusic://123456
```

How can i catch link opening or url loading for manage this type of link into the application?

it seems that there is no webview event for this, and I have not managed to find a override method.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I hope that your webview dynamically changes the url, and you need to catch the dynamically navigated url.
If so,

```
 WebView1.LoadCompleted += WebView1_LoadCompleted;
 void WebView1_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
            new MessageDialog(e.Uri.ToString()).ShowAsync();
 }
```

This code will display Message Box of the url loaded when webview navigated to an url...

If this is not you looking for, pls elaborate your scenario ..